# Angular 2.0. Difference @View @Component

Tags: angular

Hi. I'm new to Angular. I'm testing Angular 2.0.

I read the tuto [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) and the guide [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/displaying-data.html). In the tuto, the template is specified in the `@Component` annotation whereas in the guide it is in the `@View` annotation. So I was wondering what are the differences between the two approaches ? I looked up in the api preview but the explanations were not clear.

Comment: There's no real difference. [`@View is just optional`](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/4566)

Comment: Please have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40215048/1592107)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Update**

`@View()` was removed (I think in beta.13, the [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) doesn't mention it though).

**Original**

There are no differences between them. It's just sugar that you can specify all view configuration into `Component` so there's no need to import `View` decorator.

But at the same time there's a need to remain `View` decorator exist, because it allows us to use different views for the same component depending on language or media type. For example:

```
@Component(/* ... */)
@View({
  media: 'desktop',
  template: 'Template for desktop'
})
@View({
  media: 'mobile',
  template: 'Template for mobile'
})
extends class Component() {}
```

This feature is not implemented yet.

Comment: This may not hold true in future as per Igor in his comments in https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/4566 "the view switching logic will be defined elsewhere. likely via DI. we'll see."

Comment: does one component has more than one view as you described in the answer ?

Comment: @alexpods also this is not working for me 'media type' or i m not understand properly what you said. will you please provide me the demo(plnkr or fiddle) of your working code using two `@view` in the same component.

Comment: @Pardeepjain It's not implemented yet. I've just wanted to explain why we have separate `View` decorator and how it can be used in the future. I was relying on [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/596) and [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/4566) github issues. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: okay i thought this is working feature of the angular2. btw thnx for clearing difference between component and view decorators.

Answer (score 4):

As said by @Alexpods in answer and @Eric in comment before when angular2 is in alpha @view is juts optional because all the properties in the @view annotation is also included in the @component annotation so @view is just sugar that you can specify all view configuration into Component so there's no need to import View decorator.

## Updated to beta

@View has been deprecated in latest release, So you can't use it.

if you are using still @view annotation it may cause producing some kind of error. so Only Component is the place that will hold the all options.

As per officials , @View metadata decorator has been deprecated in beta.10 release.

Answer (score 2):

As per the ChangeLogs of Angular v2.0.0-beta.11, it is mentioned under breaking changes that `@View()` annotation (previously deprecated) has been removed. Apps should use the `@Component()` decorator instead.

Please have a look in Change logs of Angular2 [here.](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-10)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this **was deprecated** and now fully **gone**!

2.0.0-beta.10 (2016-03-17): **@View() annotation (previously deprecated) has been removed. Apps should use the @Component() decorator instead.**

So you don't need to worry about it anymore, The @View was previously introduced because the early thinking was that there could be multiple views in a component (like a mobile view for example) and the usage was as below:

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']})
    @View({
      media: 'desktop',
      template: '<h1>tablet<h1>'
    })
    @View({
      media: 'mobile',
      template: '<h1>mobile<h1>'
    })

    extends class Component() {}
```