# Using @View annotation vs specifying parameters in the @Component annotation

Tags: angular

In the Angular.io docs it says that "Each Angular component requires a single @Component and at least one @View annotation." [LINK](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/ViewMetadata-class.html) But even the example that it has, does not use an @View annotation.

My question is, what is the difference between using @View or specifying the parameters (templateUrl, StyleUrls, Etc.) in the @Component annotation?

Thanks guys!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401442/angular-2-0-difference-view-component

Comment: `@View()` is about to be removed https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7495

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-4) - @View is now optional (the docs are outdated).

Both options are the same - using @View as a separate annotation (for later use of different view per component) or using 'template' etc from within @Component annotation.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks @YanivEfraim! So the docs are out of date. Good to know. Yeah, because I prefer specifying all of my templates and such inside my Component annotation. But then I read on the docs that I had to use View. So I got a little confused. Thanks for the help! ;)

Comment: Here's were/when the change was made. Ref: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/4566

Answer (score 0):

As i read from the officials of angular2 there is nothing major difference between these two. 
@View is optional.
Still there is something which differentiate these two in the future:

```
@Component(/* ... */)
@View({
  media: 'Desktop',
  template: 'Template for desktop'
})
@View({
  media: 'Mobile',
  template: 'Template for Mobile'
})
extends class Component_Name() {}
```

This feature is not implemented yet.but may be used in the future as said by @alexpods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401442/angular-2-0-difference-view-component). i hope this will clear the difference upto some extent.