# Angular2 Component template vs View template

Tags: angular

In Angular2 we add annotations to a component to describe metadata for the given component. I've noticed that `ComponentMetadata` and `ViewMetadata` both have `templateUrl` and `template` properties. What is the difference between `ViewMetadata.template` (or `templateUrl`) vs `ComponentMetadata.template`, and what would be practical use cases for using one over the other?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33618041/4933038

Comment: `@View()` is about to be removed https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7495

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In one of the recent updates of angular2, @View was made optional. All of its properties moved into @Components. As of now, @View is redundant.

I my applications, I use only the Component decorators. I find this approach easy to write and maintain.

Comment: And this is why I dislike Angular 2.0. Arbitrary changes made optional, lack of documentation.

Comment: Here are the specifics on where/when @View was made redundant. Ref: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/4566

Comment: @lux The project was just released from beta. The project has consistently had 1000+ issues since the beta.0 release. Exercise a little patience, documentation will come with time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes when Component annotation provide all the functionality then why to use view annotation. according to the Documentation we can skip view annotation because component anno. provide everything which we want from view annotation. but still there is some point why to use view annotation see this answere as said by @alexpods [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33401775/5043867)