# Angular2 @View template vs @Component template

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have recently started dabbling in Angular2 & typescript - I currently program in Angular 1.x - and I am trying to figure out why both @Component and @View decorators take a `template` parameter? Is there a good reason?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34698240/5043867 Read out here for more info...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

`@View()` was removed (I think in beta.13, the [CHANGELOG.md](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) doesn't mention it though).

**Original**

It is planned to support multiple views. As long as you only have one view, there is no need to use the `@View()` annotation. Even if you use `@View()` currently there is only one view supported. Parameters you pass to `@View()` must not be passed to `@Component()` (you'd get an error anyway).

Comment: I thought the "...planned to support multiple views" concept was rejected for now. Ref: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/4566

Comment: Hmm, not sure how to interpret it. `@View()` isn't deprecated.

Comment: I don't either. The switch to incorporating the view properties into `@Component` doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Maybe they wanted a clearer distinction between `@Component` and `@Directive`. I wouldn't be surprised if `@View` is eventually deprecated. I really hope the dev team addresses the 'multiple views for different platforms' issue sometime soon.

Comment: @Satch3000 thanks for notifying :)

Comment: It would be good if Stackoverflow would have a flag to mark questions that has deprecated code. There's a lot of it everywhere. It would be a way to separate up-to-date code with old/deprecated code :)

Comment: Not sure. Almost everyone can edit questions and answers. When someone encounters an outdated answer she can add an info like I did. For me that's enough. I'm sure there are extensive discussions about this topic in http://meta.stackexchange.com/ (haven't read one myself yet though)