# In Angular 2 components should the template be defined in the component configuration object or the view configuration object?

Tags: angular

I've seen examples which show the template string in the component annotation:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'example-app',
  template: `
<h4 class="header"> Heading of {{heading}}
</h4>`
});
```

And also examples which show the template string in the view annotation:

```
@View({
template: `
<div class="row" (click)="clicked()">
<div product-image [stuff]="stuff">
  </div>
`,
  directives: [example]
})
```

What is the difference or is it simply interchangeable and it doesn't matter where you specify the template string?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401442/angular-2-0-difference-view-component