# Difference between @Component and @View

Tags: angular

I am trying to figure out what the difference is between @Component and @View in AngularJS 2.

Within the 2 following examples I can achieve the exact same thing.

Example without @View:

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'di-prototype',
  template: `
              <h1>AngularJS 2 Prototype</h1>
            `
})
export class DiPrototype {
}
```

Example with @View:

```
import {Component, View} from 'angular2/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'di-prototype'
})
@View({
  template: `
              <h1>AngularJS 2 Prototype</h1>
            `
})
export class DiPrototype {
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/33401775/4933038 (I screwed up the flag, I used a wrong question...)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2.0. Difference @View @Component](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401442/angular-2-0-difference-view-component)

Comment: @EricMartinez Thanks for the link.

Comment: You're welcome :D. Thanks @MarkRajcok, I totally screwed it up :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@View()` is about to be removed https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7495