# Angular 2 Difference between @view and @component template

Tags: angular

In Angular 2, I'm looking for an explanation on the difference between

```
@Component ({
   selector: 'test-component',
   template: '<div>Hello World</div>'
})
```

and

```
@Component ({
   selector: 'test-component',
})

@View ({ 
   template: '<div>Hello World</div>'
})
```

I have tried creating 2 components with the 2 different approaches and they both seem to behave the same. Any clarification would be helpful.

Comment: `@View()` is about to be removed https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7495

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should have a look at this question: [Angular 2.0. Difference @View @Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401442/angular-2-0-difference-view-component).

In fact, it's the same since `View` is optional but in the future, you will be able to define several views for a same component.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry