# Angular 2 @View with template vs @Component with template

Tags: javascript, angular

I am hoping someone can clear this up for me. I am assuming there is an easy answer to this. But if its out on the internet I can't seem to find it. Keep in mind, I have little angular 1 experience, so I apologize if I am missing something obvious.

I have seen the following examples out there for creating a template in Angular 2.

```
//Example 1

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app'
})

@View({
  template : '<p></p>'
})
```

As I understand it, the above example is the same as this.

```
// Example 2

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app',
   template: '<p></p>'
})
```

According to this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/View-decorator.html and this [@Directive v/s @Component in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32680244/directive-v-s-component-in-angular2)

So is there any good reason to create templates like the first example vs the second where `@View` seems to be implicitly set via `@Component` using "template:"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you should have a look at this question: [Angular 2.0. Difference @View @Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33401442/angular-2-0-difference-view-component).

Your example1 and example2 actually do the same thing...

In fact, it's the same since `View` is optional but in the future, you will be able to define several views for a same component.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of that one.. I will take a look.